# why doesn't JavaScript toLowerCase work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/CBxbT/29/, if you click the black box, a random color is selected, and then after its id is stripped down and changed to lowercase,  the random color's id is compared to whatever color you "guess" by clicking on one of the three boxes.

The fiddle works, but the same concept (i.e same code but different element names) is not working on my live site.   One my live site, I get an alert for the variable `guess`, but then I don't get anymore alerts, whereas in the fiddle, it keeps going and gives me an alert after `ran` is changed to lower case.

Is there a problem with the way I did that might be causing the problem on my live site.

```
ran = ran.toLowerCase();
```

code from fiddle

```
$("#red, #blue, #green").click(function(e) { 
     guess = $(this).attr('id'); 
     alert(guess);
     ran = ran.toLowerCase(); //works here but not on my live site
    alert(ran);
    if(ran.charAt(1) === 'f'){
        ran = ran.slice(3);
    } else
        ran = ran.slice(1);
        alert(ran);

     if (guess === ran) { 
         $('#results').fadeOut(1000);
              } else { 
                  $('#wrong').fadeOut(1000); 
                  }
 });
```

My live site [my actual site](http://eslangel.com/66-2/)

Click the start button. It will show an audio player that is randomly selected.

Click one of the spelled-out numbers from the bottom row of numbers. That is your "guess"

It should, according to the code, give you an alert of the randomly selected audio player number, but it doesn't.

relevant code from live site

```
$("#one, #two, #three, #four, #five, #six, #seven, #eight, #nine, #ten, #eleven, #twelve, #thirteen, #fourteen, #fifteen, #sixteen").click(function(e) { 
     guess = $(this).attr('id'); 
     alert(guess);
     ran = ran.toLowerCase(); 
     alert(ran);
     if(ran.charAt(1) === 'f'){
        ran = ran.slice(3);
    } else
        ran = ran.slice(1);
     alert(ran);
     if (guess === ran) { 
         $('#right').fadeIn(1000);
              } else { 
                  $('#wrong').fadeIn(1000); 
                  }
 }); 
}
```

Comment: `toLowerCase` is part of Javascript. And can you improve on your question title? Perhaps summarise the problem?

Comment: What are you seeing which suggests it's not working? And can you tell us what's different on your live site? (The correct answer is not 'nothing')

Comment: Do you see an error in the JavaScript console? Can you copy-paste the exact code from your live site? Are you sure it's that exact spot it's alerting and not someplace else (change it to `alert("foo")` to test)?

Comment: Javascript is case sensitive.. Make sure in your live version that the `toLowerCase` is written exactly like this..

Comment: ran = ran.toLowerCase();
What values had ran before this? ran isn't initialized here

Comment: Can you post the code that _doesn't_ work, rather than the code that does? I'd suspect it's something straightforward like a typo...

Comment: @Town   I posted the relevant code from my actual site, and also a link to the actual site with instructions.

Comment: Try to add `alert(ran)` before the toLowerCase line... if the variable isn't initialized, `toLowerCase` won't work.

Comment: if I click on the spelled-out numbers it gives me an alert with the number on every click

Comment: @Kreker, on the actual site (code in OP), ran was either #ONE (for example) or #f-ONE. Ran is assigned once you click "start" on the actual site.

Comment: @Kreker, if you click on the spelled out number, that is the same as the "guess" in the fiddle. In the fiddle, it then automatically tells you "ran" in an alert, but it doesn't do that in the actual site.

Comment: @Juhana, I think you are right. I added the alert, and it's saying "undefined".  The variable has already been used, so why isn't it initialized?

Comment: cause you are inside another function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the JavaScript error console, you'll see this:

```
ran is undefined
```

I suggest you start using Firebug or something similar so that you'll see the error console while you're developing.

On your live site the event for clicking on the "start" button has this line:

```
var ran = getRandom(myArray, true);
```

The `var` keyword creates a local variable called `ran`, so you're creating a new variable and not initializing the global one. Remove `var` from that line and it should work.

Comment: that's what I say before, ran hadn't a value. Btw the site posted, for me, is working correct

Comment: I am using Firebug, just I'm a bit of a newbie so I'm not that skilled with it. Anyways, can you tell me why ran is undefined if I have already been using it? How can I fix it?  Thanks if you can help.

Comment: well, thanks, that problem is solved, but it doesn't continue on and compare the way it does on the fiddle...

Comment: That's because right after initializing `ran` you change it to a jQuery object: `ran = $('#' + ran);` but later treat it as if it were a string.

Comment: I treat it as a string when I try toLowerCase()???? is that why Firebug is telling me ran.toLowerCase(); is not a function.  Can you suggest how to fix it?

Comment: Well, stop using one variable to do everything. Instead of `ran = $('#' + ran); ran.show();` do `var box = $( '#' + ran ); box.show();` or even better, `$( '#' + ran ).show();`. That way `ran` stays as a string. Similarly it's better to do `var selection = ran.toLowerCase();` etc so that the original variable stays the same.